# Stored procedure Not Accepting Newline character in parameter

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to put comma separated values as parameter to stored procedure, but when I am pressing "Enter" key for continuing the values so that it can be seen in single screen (without scrolling) , SP is not accepting the values which are provided after "Enter" key is pressed(means in new line)

```
USP_SAMPLE_SP @YEAR, @EMPIDS
```

If I am executing stored procedure as below :

```
USP_SAMPLE_SP '2016','111,222,333,444,555'
```

It is executing properly

But if I am trying to execute like below :

```
USP_SAMPLE_SP '2016','111,222,
333,444,555'
```

It is accepting all values however it is showing values up to '222' after that it is not considering any value.

Referring to "Newline" I mean is it is accepting like below :

```
USP_SAMPLE_SP '2016','111,        222,333,444,555'
```

But if I am pressing "Enter" it is not accepting values after that

If any one can explain this scenario it will be helpful.

Note: Sometimes I need to pass large number of values(ex. 1000 or above).

Please suggest if any one knows better and efficient way to do this.

First I am creating User-Defined Table Type as EMPType

```
  CREATE TYPE [dbo].[EMPType] AS TABLE(
      FinStartYear varchar(4),
      EmpId nvarchar(max) NULL
)
```

Then I am trying to pass those values for altering my stored procedure as below :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [USP_SAMPLE_SP]   
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here  
  @FinStartYear EMPType readonly ,  
 @EmpIDs  EMPType  readonly

AS
```

But when I hover mouse over the parameter it shows me below error :

```
The Parameter '@FinStartYear' cannot be declared READONLY since it is not table valued parameter.   

The Parameter '@EmpIDs' cannot be declared READONLY since it is not table valued parameter.
```

But when I am trying to alter the stored procedure it is showing me below error :

```
    Must declare the scalar variable "@EmpIDs".
    Must declare the scalar variable "@FinStartYear"
```

When I hover over 'EMPType' it shows me below error :

```
Parameter or variable '@FinStartYear' has an invalid datatype.
```

NOTE : Under Programmability -> Types -> User-Defined Table Types ->dbo.EMPType

It is showing me EMPType has been created.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to be certain without seeing the code of your stored procedure, but I suspect that the newline character somehow breaks the code which is used to split the delimited string into a result set; the newline character is interpreted as a terminator and all the values following it are ignored.

There are several possible solutions.

One is to build your list of input values from a series of shorter strings, enabling you to control how the list appears on the screen without affecting its content. Note that this requires the use of a variable:

```
-- I am guessing the data type of the @EMPIDS parameter. Use a matching type for @IDS
DECLARE @IDS VARCHAR(MAX) = '111,222,'       
                             + '333,444,555'

EXEC USP_SAMPLE_SP @YEAR = '2016', @EMPIDS = @IDS
```

Another would be to amend the code of the stored procedure to strip out newline characters before splitting the delimited list. I wouldn't recommend this, since this behaviour might be relied on by other users of the code.

---

**Edit**

Here's an example of how to replace newline characters:

```
DECLARE @EMPID varchar(100) = '111,222,
333,444,555'

SET @EMPID = REPLACE(REPLACE(@EMPID,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')

SELECT @EMPID
```

Before you use this, make sure you're not going to affect any other users of this code who might rely on the current behaviour.

---

Another solution would be to amend the stored procedure to accept a [table-valued parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb510489(v=sql.110).aspx) rather than a delimited list. This is a little more complex to set up but likely to perform than better than splitting a delimited string, especially if the string contains thousands of values.

---

**Edit 2**

I think you might have misunderstood how a table-valued parameter works. It enables you to completely avoid the concatenated list of EMPIDs, and instead work with a table variable containing one EMPID per row which can be passed as an argument to a stored procedure.

Here's a worked example:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.EMPType AS TABLE(
      EmpId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
GO

-- I don't know what your procedure does so I've created a simple stub
-- which shows how to use the table-valued parameter like a table
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.USP_SAMPLE_SP
    @FinStartYear varchar(4),
    @empids EMPType readonly
AS
    SELECT @FinStartYear AS out_year, EmpId
    FROM    @empids
    ORDER BY EmpId
GO

-- use the code from here to the end of the example every time
-- you want to execute the procedure (setting the list of EMPID values appropriately
DECLARE @in_emp EMPType --declare an instance of EMPType as a variable

INSERT @in_emp(EmpId) VALUES (111),(333),(222),(555),(444) --insert some values into the variable

EXEC dbo.USP_SAMPLE_SP @FinStartYear = '2016',@empids = @in_emp --pass the variable as a parameter to the stored procedure
GO
```

Comment: Thanks...can you please tell me how to remove the NewLine character from the string.

Comment: Actually I am using SplitString function and I am passing @EMPIDS parameter to it.
I tried using LTRIM and RTRIM functions on it but it is not working

Comment: @Shardul - see my update. SplitString is not the name of a built-in SQL Server function, so without seeing the code it's impossible to know how it behaves.

Comment: Edharper I tried the same thing but in different manner SET @EMPID = REPLACE(@EMPID,CHAR(13)+char(10))  but with some 100 values only I can fell the performance difference. I would like to try another way as you suggested of using table-valued parameter. I trid doing it using table - valued parameter but I am finding it quite difficult. It will helpful if you can help me in doing this.

Comment: @Shardul - edit your question to include details of what you've tried when using a table-valued parameter, and give details of where you're getting stuck

Comment: @Shardul - I've added an example of how to use a table-valued parameter based on the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The example you have given is really helpful. But I think it can be used when we are automating the stored procedure via job and it will be getting values from some other stored procedure or function.

Comment: So I think I have to write another stored procedure which will contain the table-valued parameter and then I have to call this stored procedure inside the new stored procedure and pass the table-valued parameter(which will contain all the empids) as input parameter to current stored procedure(USP_SAMPLE_SP).
This is my understanding as per the example.
However in my situation I have to manually pass the EmpIds.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Shardul - you can call a stored procedure with a table-valued parameter from an ad-hoc SQL statement; I don't know why you think you need another procedure. I've updated the example to make the code you'd need to use (hopefully) more obvious

Comment: I just wanted to make this stored procedure user-friendly.
User need not to think about what is table-valued parameter and how to pass it. My intention is - user will just pass the comma separated values to the stored procedure and get the desired output.
But thanks for your great help your suggestion were really helpful.